# VS2010 setup project - Launch application after install as administrator using PostBuildEvent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have a Winform application that was developed using VS2010 C# I created an installer(setup) project and everything worked great. The main application changes the network metric of a proprietary network adapter and has to be run as administrator to function properly. This was done by adding an app.manifest with `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

Then we decided that we want the option to launch the app directly after install. I did this by adding the following PostBuildEvent: **cscript.exe "$(ProjectDir)EnableLaunchApplication.js" "$(BuiltOuputPath)"** The .js file can be found on Aaron Stebner's blog at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx The only thing I changed was the name of the .exe that is called.

Now my application is started after the install, no problem. Only issue is that it is not started with elevated privileges so it does not function properly! If I close the application after install and start it from the desktop shortcut or the programs menu it is started with elevated privileges and working as expected.

The .js file is something that I do not really know how to debug so this is a bit of a blind spot to me. I think I must at some point add the ability there to start the app in admin mode but I have no clue how, any help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but from what I read, I think a custom action would launch with the credentials used during the installation (see [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19560/Launching-Your-Application-After-Install-using-Vis)).